# \text does not work in a matplotlib label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib together with latex labels for the axis, title and colorbar labels

While it works really great most of the time, it has some issues when you have a formula using \text.

One really simple example.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.title(r"$f_{\text{cor, r}}$")

plt.show()
```

This will result in an error message like:

```
IPython/core/formatters.py:239: FormatterWarning: Exception in image/png formatter: 
f_{\text{1cor, r}}
   ^
Unknown symbol: \text (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)
  FormatterWarning,
```

Is there an easy way to use \text in there?

Comment: [LATEX Mathematical Symbols](https://www.caam.rice.edu/~heinken/latex/symbols.pdf) & [matplotlib: Rendering math equations using TeX](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`\text` won't work because it requires the *amsmath* package (not included in mathtext - the math rendering engine of matplotlib). So you basically have two options:

- use latex based font rendering

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amsmath}'] #for \text command
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.title(r"$f_{\text{cor, r}}$")
plt.show()
```

2. use mathtext but use `\mathrm` instead of `\text`

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False  # not really needed
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.title(r"$f_{\mathrm{cor, r}}$")
plt.show()
```

The latter approach creates a figure like
[image]
Be aware that unlike with the `\text` command, spaces inside the `\mathrm` environment are not respected. If you want more space between the variables you have to use latex style commands (`\<space>`, `\;`, ...).

Comment: Thank you! Especially for the actual explanation why it behaves like that.

Comment: If you want to export your plot as pgf you also need mpl.rcParams['pgf.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amsmath}']

Comment: The first method may turn out to screw some other standard `mathplotlib` features. For example, `ticklabel_format`'s `scilimit` uses `\mathdefault`, which my TeX Live does not recognize as a command.

Comment: @DanielBöckenhoff Gnaaarrrrrr... or in cases like mine, when you uncomment `fig.savefig('name.pgf')` and the error pops up, you need both, `text.latex.preamble` and `pgf.preamble` set. E.g. add `plt.rcParams.update({ "text.latex.preamble": plt.rcParams["pgf.preamble"] })`

You let me on the right track! Thank you!

Comment: When I try the first, I get : `ValueError: Key text.latex.preamble: Could not convert ['\\usepackage{amsmath}'] to str`. Do you know what the problem might be or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to let matplot lib [use LaTeX directly](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html) for your text rendering (rather than the [mathtext](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) implementation that matplotlib provides).

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
# (create your plot as before)
plt.title(r"$f_{\mathrm{cor, r}}$")
```

This requires a fully working LaTeX installation.  I can't seem to get it to recognise `\text`, but `\mathrm` does work (for 'roman family' font) just fine.

Comment: Sure, this solves the problem, though often I would like to keep normal rendering for the rest of it.

Comment: yes, I agree (and generally try to avoid full LaTeX when plotting if I can).  It seems that I was wrong about the `mathrm` environment requiring the `text.usetex` config setting - @Jakob's answer shows that it is implemented in mathtext.

Comment: `\mathrm` doesn't preserve spaces