# \frac{}{} doesn't work in plt.text?

Tags: matplotlib, text, latex, keyerror

I am trying to add a text to my plot, using latex. Latex and \frac{}{} works well in titles and labels, but I can not get it work in plt.text(). I tried both, using raw or double backslash.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axhline(x=30, c='k')
plt.text(0,0,r'$\frac{\Gamma_M}{\Gamma_D}$ = 10')
plt.xlabel(r'$\frac{\Gamma_M}{\Gamma_D}$')
```

It works for label (if you outcomment text line) but not for text, gives me this output:

```
KeyError: '\\Gamma_M'
```

Comment: What version of matplotlib do you use? I can obtain text perfectly in math notation. I have matplotlib 2.2.2.

Comment: I am also running matplotlib 2.2.2 in Python 2.7.15rc1 or Python 3.6.5, same KeyError.

Comment: Does this help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824687/text-does-not-work-in-a-matplotlib-label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824687/text-does-not-work-in-a-matplotlib-label)?

Comment: @AmitSingh As far as I understand, your request is about text rendering inside mathmode, but I have problems only with \frac{}{}, everything else works perfectly. Also, when I try to add lines as requested in your post I get the following error:
`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex' `

Comment: I guess it is indeed more a setup problem. All LaTeX works fine for me. (I do get an error on `plt.axhline(x=30, c='k')`: Unknown property x.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is interpreting the `{}` as part of the python format strings, not LaTeX. Use double braces instead:

```py
plt.text(0,0,r'$\frac{{\Gamma_M}}{{\Gamma_D}}$ = 10')
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. But I am still wondering why does it work without double braces for some guys in previous comments? :)