# Using \text in LATEX in Matplotlib

Tags: macos, matplotlib, latex

In continuation of the following question:

[\text does not work in a matplotlib label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824687/text-does-not-work-in-a-matplotlib-label)
and [RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58121461/runtimeerror-failed-to-process-string-with-tex-because-latex-could-not-be-found)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amsmath}'] #for \text command
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.xlabel(r"$\frac{\text{Actual Value of Production}}{Demand}$", fontsize=16)

plt.show()
```

I got the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found
```

Which means that the latex should be installed locally.

(Is there any other work around?)

In [matplotlib "manual"](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/usetex.html) says, that the following packages needed:

- LaTeX
- dvipng
- Ghostscript

Is there more simple work around to use a `\text` command in Latex ?

If not what is the most easies way to install above in OSX ?

Answer (score 5):

According to this [Matplotlib's documentation section](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/mathtext.html), you can use the restricted TeX that comes with matplotlib without having to install any LaTeX distribution locally:

> You can use a subset TeX markup in any matplotlib text string by placing it inside a pair of dollar signs ($).
>
> **Note that you do not need to have TeX installed**, since Matplotlib ships its own TeX expression parser, layout engine, and fonts.

The error you get comes from the `mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True` statement which forces Matplotlib to link the TeX interpreter to you local (non-existing) LaTeX distribution. Now I understand that you did it in order to have access to the `\text` function that does not exist in the native Matplotlib's TeX distribution.

So two solutions:

- You can use the `\mathrm` command and enforce space between words with `\,` (ugly but simple workaround)

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
plt.xlabel(r'$\frac{\mathrm{Actual\,Value\,of\,Production}}\mathrm{{Demand}}$', fontsize=16)

plt.show()
```

- If you do not like this solution, then you should install LaTeX locally. On OS X, you can get it from [MacTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/).

Comment: Regarding `MacTex` I was bit afraid, to install it since it's about 2-3 Gb and also `dviping` is needed which seems to have not straight forward install.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post. The `dvipng` package should come with MacTeX – I never installed it and Matplotlib + LaTeX work perfectly on my OSX. And indeed, MacTeX is quite large I agree. If you only want to write expression in Matplotlib, this is probably an overkill unless you plan to often use more-than-basic function.

Comment: Maybe it could be also interesting to suggest Matplotlib to inclue the `\text` function in the minimal TeX distribution they provide.